# VB.NET - get Java absolute path in any Windows version and configuration

Tags: java, vb.net, windows, path

I'm developing an application in VB.NET which launches another application in Java. When I was testing my VB.NET app on various Windows configurations I've ran into a big problem. Some users do have Java installed but they don't have their JAVA_PATH set properly, thus `Shell("cmd.exe /c java -Xmx1G" & ... )` doesn't work. I wrote a function which is searching java.exe in `\Program Files(x86)\Java\` and `\Program Files\Java\`, but it doesn't work on Windows 8. I've also tried searching the path in Windows registry but it doesn't work on Win8 too. (Both of the workarounds work on Win7)

What is the best way of getting `java.exe` absolute path under any Windows version (>=XP) and configuration?

Comment: Why doesnt it work on Windows 8? Do you go an error message? It is supposed to work with your workaround.

Comment: It turned out that my friend who helped me in testing the application had Java installed on another partition, so I wrote a function which searches every partition for path \ProgramFiles[(x86)]\Java and returns first found. Thanks for help anyway.